# maven prevent denpendency compile

Tags: maven, dependencies, compiler-warnings, skip

I have a custom jar which including java sources; Maven tries to compile when it builds. How do I skip source compile in the jar file? I have tried such as exclude with some pattern in the compiler-plug in and source directory define but I have not get any luck. Thanks!

C05

Answer (score 3):

This is a normal behavior of **[`javac`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)** that searches the whole classpath for source files to compile unless the `-sourcepath` option is given (and this would be the solution here).

Unfortunately, there is a Jira issue about `-sourcepath` not being passed to `javac` by the Maven Compiler Plugin (see [MCOMPILER-98](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-98)). But there is a workaround:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArguments>
      <sourcepath>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourcepath>
    </compilerArguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```